# Is it possible to get the calculated "minimum" height for a VStack in Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui, frame, vstack

I'm working with a card-like view, and I would essentialy like to know the minimum height needed to house the elements, and then add a border around that.

this becomes difficult since VStack and HStack seem to want to take up the most space possible, so I need to manually insert a `.frame(...)` to coercse this to work, but that makes it very unflexible.

In the picture I'm highlighting the `VStack` which, as you can see, is overfilling beyond the constraints of the 48px frame height.

code

```swift
var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
      Image("cocktail")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .padding(Size.Spacing.unit * 2)
        .background(self.color)
        .cornerRadius(8)
        .overlay(
          RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
            .stroke(self.color)
      )


      HStack(spacing: 0) {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
          Text("Negroni").font(.headline)
          Spacer()
          HStack {
            Tag(name: "bitter")
            Tag(name: "sweet")
            Tag(name: "strong")
          }
        }
        .padding(.leading, 10)
        Spacer()
      }
    }
    .padding(Size.Spacing.unit * 2)
    .frame(height: 48.0)
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> since VStack and HStack seem to want to take up the most space possible

This assumption is incorrect - by default stacks are tight to content and content tight to minimum with default padding between UI elements. In provided code it is `Spacer()` responsibility on expanding to max available space. So to make minimum space for content, highlighted `VStack` should be changed as follows:

```
VStack(spacing: 0, alignment: .leading) {
  Text("Negroni").font(.headline)
  HStack {
    Tag(name: "bitter")
    Tag(name: "sweet")
    Tag(name: "strong")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe i misunderstand you, but i tried your example...unfortunately it was not compilable, so i had to change some things. but as you can see the result (vstack - yellow) is not taking to much space, maybe because of your padding?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
      HStack(spacing: 0) {
        Image("cocktail")
          .resizable()
          .scaledToFit()
      //    .padding(Size.Spacing.unit * 2)
            .background(Color.blue)
          .cornerRadius(8)
          .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                .stroke(Color.yellow)
        )


        HStack(spacing: 0) {
          VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Negroni").font(.headline)
            Spacer()
            HStack {
              Text("bitter")
              Text("sweet")
              Text("strong")
            }
          }
          .background(Color.yellow)
          .padding(.leading, 10)
          Spacer()
        }.background(Color.red)
      }
   //   .padding(Size.Spacing.unit * 2)
      .frame(height: 48.0)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, this is much better, but not exactly what I was trying to do. Let me rephrase a bit.

this works to make sure the text is not taking up too much space, but I also wanted the blue image to fill to that minimum height. Ideally without the `.frame(height: 40)` being hard coded